# One MEX-file to rule all functions and in the DLL to bind them

Tags: visual-studio, matlab, fortran, mex, intel-fortran

I was using Intel Fortran to compile MEX-files to be used in MATLAB. (MEX-files are dll's exposing code, fortran function in my case, to MATLAB.) To each Fortran function I wanted to expose to MATLAB was associated one MEX-file. Initially I was doing this in the command line, and wanted to move to visual studio. The visual studio example for one function [is here](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100208-how-can-i-compile-fortran-mex-files-in-microsoft-visual-studio?s_tid=mwa_osa_a).

As I have quite a lot of functions, I wouldn't like to create one visual studio project per function, and I would prefer to have one DLL MEX-file containing all Fortran functions I'd like to export to MATLAB. Can this be done, and if so, how ?

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB, each MEX-file implements one MATLAB function. However, you can write your MEX-file function such that it accepts as first argument a string, which indicates which of your Fortran functions you'd like to call. For example, you'd have a command:

```
out = my_mex_gate('function1', arg1, arg2);
```

If you don't like the syntax (I wouldn't be surprised) then put this MEX-file in a sub-directory called `private`, such that it's not accessible from outside the directory, and write M-file functions that call your private MEX-files:

```
function out = function1(arg1,arg2)
   out = my_mex_gate('function1',arg1,arg2);
```

You still need to write one M-file for each of the functions you want to expose. But since these M-files should contain also the documentation to each function, the files are useful beyond simplifying syntax.

Your directory structure will look like this:

```
  Ftoolbox/
     +- function1.m
     +- function2.m
     +- function3.m
     +- private/
           +- my_mex_gate.mex
```

Pick a meaningful name instead of `Ftoolbox`. You then add this directory to your MATLAB path:

```matlab
addpath /path/to/Ftoolbox
```

making all these functions available within MATLAB no matter what the current directory is.

---

Within the MEX-file, the entry point (`mexFunction`) checks only the first input argument. Based on its value, it will call one of a series of internal functions. Each of these checks and converts the rest of the input arguments, and calls the relevant Fortran function. These functions are more or less the way that individual `mexFunction`s would be.  Therefore, there are no requirements for the various Fortran functions to have similar sets of input arguments.

[This is an example of such a MEX-file in C++](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/dipimage/private/dip_math.cpp), in Fortran you can do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Is there a way to handle the fact that the functions "pointed" by the string can have different number of arguments without passing arguments in an array ?

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj Yes, that’s no problem. You can first check the first input argument, and depending on its value do something different with the other arguments. Here’s an example from a project of mine:  https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/dipimage/private/dip_math.cpp — it’s C++ but the concept is the same. That file uses helper functions (check input type is correct type etc) defined here: https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/include/dip_matlab_interface.h